# How to access nested formArray controls validation errors in angular9?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an angular app in which i have a `reactive` form like this

```
this.shipperEditForm = this.fb.group({
  shipperID: [this.shipperId, Validators.required],
  companyAddress: ['', Validators.required],
  companyClassifications: ['', Validators.required],
  companyType: [''],
  poc: this.fb.array([this.createPOC()]),
  paymentTypeId: [''],
  paymentCreditId: [],
  monthlyShipmentId: ['']
})

createPOC() {
 return this.fb.group({
   firstName: ['', Validators.required],
   designation: ['', Validators.required],
   email: ['', Validators.required],
   role: ['', Validators.required],
   phone: ['', Validators.required]
  })
}

get frm1() { return this.shipperEditForm.controls; }
get poc() { return this.frm1.poc as FormArray; }
```

And in my `template` i am checking for `validation` errors like this

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let pocControl of poc.controls; let i = index">
    <div class="form-row w-100 pl-3 pr-3" [formGroup]="pocControl">
      <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 ">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control com-input" formControlName="firstName" maxlength="25"
            (keypress)="vs.allowLettersOnly($event)" maxlength="25" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid' : poc.controls[i].get('firstName').errors &&
            (poc.controls[i].get('firstName').errors.touched || poc.controls[i].get('firstName').errors.dirty)}"/>
            <span class="help-block" *ngIf="poc.controls[i].get('firstName').errors &&
            (poc.controls[i].get('firstName').errors.touched || poc.controls[i].get('firstName').errors.dirty)">
              <span *ngIf="poc.controls[i].get('firstName').errors.required" class="text-danger">
                {{constants.errors.required.name}}
              </span>
            </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-lg-4">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label> </label>
          <button class="btn btn-primary mt-lg-4 border-radius-zero" (click)="addPocItem(i)"
            *ngIf="i === poc.controls.length - 1">+ Add Another POC</button>
          <button class="btn btn-primary mt-lg-4 border-radius-zero" (click)="removePocItem(i)"
            *ngIf="i !== poc.controls.length - 1">- Remove POC</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

But the issue is that "Name" field doesn't producing `required` `validation` error and also field is also not turning into red that means error is not accessible inside of template. But i don't know why?
How can i `access` nested `formArray` validation `errors` inside my `template` ?

Note: This is not full form code. Because form is too large to share that's why i just included the `formArray` part.

Comment: As you said yourself, this form is already quite large and apparently it's even bigger that the shared code. We wrote a library to help angular devs break their huge forms into sub forms in case you're interested: https://github.com/cloudnc/ngx-sub-form and one thing that may be of interest here: We handle nested errors (see https://github.com/cloudnc/ngx-sub-form#type-safety-you-said and `formGroupErrors`)

Comment: thanx @maxime1992 for sharing a library. Will look into it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. Now it's working with this

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label>Name</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control com-input" formControlName="firstName" maxlength="25"
            (keypress)="vs.allowLettersOnly($event)" maxlength="25" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid' : pocControl.get('firstName').errors &&
            (pocControl.get('firstName').touched || pocControl.get('firstName').dirty)}"/>
  <span class="help-block" *ngIf="pocControl.get('firstName').errors &&
            (pocControl.get('firstName').touched || pocControl.get('firstName').dirty)">
     <span *ngIf="pocControl.get('firstName').errors.required" class="text-danger">
                {{constants.errors.required.name}}
     </span>
  </span>
/div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go to on any level with

```
this.shipperEditForm.control.get('poc.firstName').valid
```

Answer (score 0):

Error object does not contain touched property. you should use touched property on FormControl class

```
poc.controls[i].get('firstName').errors.touched ==> poc.controls[i].get('firstName').touched
```

**component.html**

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let pocControl of poc.controls; let i = index">
    <div class="form-row w-100 pl-3 pr-3" [formGroup]="pocControl">
      <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 ">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control com-input" formControlName="firstName" maxlength="25"
            (keypress)="vs.allowLettersOnly($event)" maxlength="25" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid' : poc.controls[i].get('firstName').errors &&
            (poc.controls[i].get('firstName').errors.touched || poc.controls[i].get('firstName').errors.dirty)}"/>
            <span class="help-block" *ngIf="poc.controls[i].get('firstName').errors &&
            (poc.controls[i].get('firstName').touched || poc.controls[i].get('firstName').dirty)">
              <span *ngIf="poc.controls[i].get('firstName').errors.required" class="text-danger">
                {{constants.errors.required.name}}
              </span>
            </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-lg-4">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label> </label>
          <button class="btn btn-primary mt-lg-4 border-radius-zero" (click)="addPocItem(i)"
            *ngIf="i === poc.controls.length - 1">+ Add Another POC</button>
          <button class="btn btn-primary mt-lg-4 border-radius-zero" (click)="removePocItem(i)"
            *ngIf="i !== poc.controls.length - 1">- Remove POC</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```